# Could you explain to me this equation?

Tags: arithmetic, rationalising-denominator

Could someone explain to me this equation ?

$W =  5\sqrt 2 + \sqrt3 $

$\frac{1}{w} = \frac {5\sqrt2 - \sqrt3}{47}$

Why does
W+$\frac{1}{w}$

= $5\sqrt 2 + \sqrt3 +\frac {5\sqrt2 - \sqrt3}{47}$

= $5\sqrt 2 + \sqrt3 +\frac {5\sqrt2}{47} - \frac {\sqrt3}{47}$

equal

$= \frac {240\sqrt2+46\sqrt3}{47}$

Comment: Exercise in rationalizing the denominator of $\frac1w$

Comment: $5\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3} + \frac{5\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{3}}{47} = \frac{47\cdot(5\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})+5\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{3}}{47}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$W =  5\sqrt 2 + \sqrt3 $

$\frac{1}{w} = \frac {5\sqrt2 - \sqrt3}{47}$

What is:
W+$\frac{1}{w}$ ?

$$5\sqrt 2 + \sqrt 3 + \frac{5\sqrt 2 + \sqrt 3}{47}$$
$$\frac {47(5\sqrt 2 + \sqrt 3)}{47} + \frac{5\sqrt 2 + \sqrt 3}{47}$$
$$\frac {235 \sqrt2 + 47 \sqrt 3 + 5 \sqrt 2 - \sqrt 3}{47}$$
$$\frac {240 \sqrt 2 + 46 \sqrt 3}{47}$$